# ¿Cómo cambiar posición de elementos de un arreglo y luego rotar?

Tags: java, array

En este caso el elemento que esta en N=3, lo debo mover a la posición 7 y desplazar el elemento que ya se encuentra en la posición 7.

Ejemplo de esta imagen, resulta que sé cómo hacer desplazarla el arreglo pero las cosas que he intentado solo he logrado sustituir el elemento de la 7 posición, por el de la 3, y repetirlos, no es ningún tipo de trabajo solo estoy aprendiendo JAVA por mi cuenta.

Código que uso para desplazar los elementos del arreglo

```
for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length-1; j++) {
  aux=numeros[1+i];
  numeros[1+i]=numeros[0];
  numeros[0]=aux;  
}
```

Este es el ejercicio:

> Realiza un programa que pida 10 números por teclado y que los almacene en
>   un array. A continuación se mostrará el contenido de ese array junto al índice
>   (0 – 9). Seguidamente el programa pedirá dos posiciones a las que llamaremos
>   “inicial” y “final”. Se debe comprobar que inicial es menor que final y que
>   ambos números están entre 0 y 9. El programa deberá colocar el número de
>   la posición inicial en la posición final, rotando el resto de números para que no
>   se pierda ninguno. Al final se debe mostrar el array resultante.
>   Por ejemplo, para inicial = 3 y final = 7:
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No sería más lógico desplazar los elementos en las posiciones 4,5,6 y 7 hacia la izquierda y poner en la posición 7 el elemento que estaba en la posición 3? En cualquier deberías añadir el código con el que has intentado resolver el problema

Comment: @YONIBER ENCARNACION Podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar el codigo

Comment: Realiza un programa que pida 10 números por teclado y que los almacene en
un array. A continuación se mostrará el contenido de ese array junto al índice
(0 – 9). Seguidamente el programa pedirá dos posiciones a las que llamaremos
“inicial” y “final”. Se debe comprobar que inicial es menor que final y que
ambos números están entre 0 y 9. El programa deberá colocar el número de
la posición inicial en la posición final, rotando el resto de números para que no
se pierda ninguno. Al final se debe mostrar el array resultante.
Por ejemplo, para inicial = 3 y final = 7:

Comment: @PabloLozano Este es el ejercicio estoy aprendiendo java de un libro, entonces ya aprendi a desplazar los arreglos pero hacer este cambio de posiciones con los objetos del arreglo me tiene de malas.

Comment: Añade el código que tienes para desplazar, eso ya sería un paso adelante

Comment: @PabloLozano Este el el algoritmo que uso para desplazarlos
 for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length-1; j++) {
              aux=numeros[1+i];
           numeros[1+i]=numeros[0];
           numeros[0]=aux;  
            }

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código ahí, no como un comentario, será mucho más legible. Luego puedes borrar el comentario anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice una solución para tu problema, esta poco estilosa pero funciona, traté de comentarla para que la entendieras, la dejo por acá:

```
public static  void test(){
    int posInicial = 3;
    int posFinal = 7;
    //crear el array inicial
    int[] arrayInicial = {20,5,7,4,32,9,2,14,11,6};
    int[] arrayFinal = desplazamiento(arrayInicial,posInicial,posFinal);
    System.out.println("RESULTADO:");
    //mostrar resultados
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFinal.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i+") "+arrayFinal[i]);
    }
}

private static int[] desplazamiento(int[] arrayInicial, int posInicial, int posFinal){
    int[] arrayFinal = new int[10];

    //Hacer una copia de tu array original, para que en caso de no cumplirse alguna condición devolver el array original
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInicial.length; i++) {
        arrayFinal[i] = arrayInicial[i];
    }

    // condiciones del problema
    if(posInicial >=0 && posFinal <10 && posInicial < posFinal){
        int numInicial = arrayInicial[posInicial];
        arrayFinal[posFinal] = numInicial; // hacer el remplazo del numero inicial por el final
        for (int i = posFinal; i < arrayInicial.length-1; i++) { // hacer los desplazamientos de la posicion final a la derecha
            arrayFinal[i+1] = arrayInicial[i];
        }
        arrayFinal[0] = arrayInicial[arrayInicial.length-1]; // indicar la ultima posicion del array original, como la primera del nuevo array
        for (int i = 1; i <= posInicial; i++) { // indicar los desplazamientos de la primera posicion del array hasta la posicion inicial
            arrayFinal[i] = arrayInicial[i - 1];
        }
    }
    return arrayFinal;
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos :)

Comment: Efectivamente me resulta que me recomiendas para aprender a resolver este tipo de algortimos?

Comment: Mi recomendación es que no empieces codeando sino que te tomes tu tiempo pensando la solución en papel.

Comment: Gracias pero ya lo resolví, buen consejo!